# index of all entries for WordPress blogs

Tags: http, api, wordpress

I'm an avid reader of several WordPress(.com) blogs. Is there a simple way (via the API rather than screen scraping) to get an index of all posts (with date, title and URL) so I don't have to manually wade through the back archives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only public 'API' you'll have available is the RSS (or Atom) feed, but this usually only shows the 10 most recent posts.

The XML RPC would have been the alternative, but I'm sure that requires authentication.

Other than that, as you say, your only option would be some rudimentary form of screen scraping.